# Spring Loaded not picking up changes (Run via Command Line / Edit using IntelliJ)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-loaded

I have a very basic Spring Boot application that i use to run inside a terminal windows using.

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

To use Spring Loaded i have modified my pom.xml to auto attach the reloading agent.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the console window i see that the reloading agent is attached.

But when i open the Maven Project inside IntelliJ and modify some code the reloading does not take place. I tried to manually compile the modified classes but this also seems not to have any effect.

What am i missing??

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that Java 8 Update 40 broke the compatibility. So a downgrade to Java 8 Update 31 solved the issue.